# Selenium stopped working. Error received: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

My python script to browse a website in headless mode using selenium was working fine for a long time but it stopped working suddenly. 'Submit' button on [this][1] page was clickable easily but not anymore.

This is part of my code which is not working anymore:

```py
    def result(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        global stop_alert, chat_id
        upd = bot.get_updates()
        chat_id = upd[0].message.from_user.id
        try:
            if platform.startswith('win'):
                ser = Service("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe")
                op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                op.headless = True
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)

            else:
                ser = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
                op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                op.headless = True
                op.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)


        except Exception as e:
            update.message.reply_text(f'<b>Exception occurred in result function\n'
                                      f'while creating driver object</b>\n'
                                      f' {str(e)}', parse_mode='HTML')
            return

        reply = f"\U00002764<b> Welcome to Results on BSE Bot </b>\U00002764\n" \
                f"&#x1F575; {len(companies)} company(s) to scan &#x1F575;"
        update.message.reply_text(reply, parse_mode='HTML')
        channel_msg_id = ''
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        while True:
            if not stop_alert:
                if companies:
                    for i in list(companies):
                        try:
                            driver.get(i)
                            wait.until(
                                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.whitebox img[src*='loader']")))
                            wait.until_not(
                                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.whitebox img[src*='loader']")))
                            select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ddlPeriod'))
                            select.select_by_value('Result')
                            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@value="Submit"]').click()
                            table_data = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@id='lblann']")))
                        except Exception as e:
                            reply = f"\U00002764 Exception occurred. {str(e)} \U00002764"
                            update.message.reply_text(reply, parse_mode='HTML')
                            companies.remove(i)
                            continue
                        try:
                            exch_rec_date = table_data.find_element(
                                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lblann"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/b[1]'). \
                                get_attribute("innerHTML")
                            exch_rec_date_modified = datetime.strptime(exch_rec_date, ' %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S').date()
                            company_name = table_data.find_element(
                                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lblann"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a').get_attribute("innerHTML")
                            heading = table_data.find_element(
                                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lblann"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a'). \
                                get_attribute("innerHTML")
                            link_pdf = table_data.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='tablebluelink']").get_attribute(
                                'href')
                            exch_rec_time = table_data.find_element(
                                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lblann"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/b[1]'). \
                                get_attribute("innerHTML")

This is the error message:

    Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (217, 1879)
      (Session info: headless chrome=107.0.5304.107)
    Stacktrace:
    Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00471ED3+2236115]
        Ordinal0 [0x004092F1+1807089]


  [1]: https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/tanla-platforms-ltd/tanla/532790/corp-announcements/
```

Comment: This happens when another element overlaps the element you want to click. If you run the test under different resolution this might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the elements to be clickable.
First of all this related to the submit button you are clicking, but I'd add this check also before selecting the `Result` since I see when the page is opened spinner is appeared until the page is loaded.
So, I'd change your code to be as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

for i in list(companies):
    try:
        driver.get(i)
        wait.until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.whitebox img[src*='loader']")))
        select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ddlPeriod'))
        select.select_by_value('Result')
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@value="Submit"]'))).click()
        table_data = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@id='lblann']")))
    except Exception as e:
        reply = f"\U00002764 Exception occurred. {str(e)} \U00002764"
        update.message.reply_text(reply, parse_mode='HTML')
        companies.remove(i)
        continue
```

Comment: It threw an error in pycharm in this line:     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, div.whitebox img[src *= 'loader'])))
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

Comment: where did you get this: div.whitebox img[src*='loader']

Comment: I forgot the apostrophes. Please let me know if any more problems with my suggestion

Comment: Used your edited code. still facing the same problem. Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (217, 1855)
  (Session info: headless chrome=107.0.5304.107)

Comment: Well, this is a common problem with Selenium. To resolve it I will have to actually debug this. Can you share all your code including the content of `companies`?

Comment: added the code in the question. Can you give me the xpath of the submit button? I am unable to detect it.

Comment: Your XPath locator `//input[@value="Submit"]` is good enough

Comment: I will try to debug your code later when I have a time

Comment: sorry, I wanted the xpath code of the loader(spinner). I am not able to pause the chrome on it. whats the trick to pause chrome at the spinner?

Comment: In dev tools open the Sources tab. Press F8 to pause. So, after performing some action when page is being reloaded do this.

Comment: using network throttling 3G but F8 not pausing the chrome

Comment: network throttling is not on Sources tab. But OK, do what you want

Comment: I want the xpath of the spinner.

Comment: I already explained you how to pause scripts execution on the page

Comment: got it. but no luck so far. spinner presence is not being detected at all

Comment: When I played with that page manually changing the number inside the URL I saw that sometimes spinner appeared and sometimes not

Comment: in my case, spinner was there but the script didn't detect it at all